# What is sum of totatives of n(natural numbers $ \lt n$ coprime to $n$ )?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, divisibility, prime-factorization

Same question as in title:

What is sum of natural numbers that are coprime to $n$ and are $ \lt n$ ?

I know how to count number of them using Euler's function, but how to calculate sum?

Comment: What's a totative of $n$?

Comment: Did you try the google? @Bernard https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totative

Comment: I see, it's just the units modulo $n$.

Comment: @Bernard Technically, not true, because $n+1$ is a unit modulo $n$. They are the least positive representatives of the units modulo $n$.

Comment: Addressed to the OP: see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Famous_Theorems_of_Mathematics/Number_Theory/Totient_Function#Sum_of_integers_relatively_prime_to_and_less_than_or_equal_to_n.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: it was implicit (one always thinks in terms of $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$).

Comment: But then you can't talk about the sum of the elements and get anything other than zero. @Bernard Yes, I'm being pedantic, but it is good to be cautious when helping people using terms like "totative."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Are you saying that, when posting questions, we should not explain anything that can be googled? I were soliciting free help from a stranger, I think I'd try to make it as easy for him as I can.

Answer (score 5):

Let's call this function $f$. Then $$f(n) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} \delta_{1}^{\gcd(i, n)} i = \frac{n \phi(n)}{2},$$ where $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta function and $\phi$ is Euler's totient function. Clearly if $n$ is prime, then $f(n) = T_{n - 1}$, where $T_n$ is the $n$th triangular number.

Work a few examples. I'll do two for you: $f(6) = 1 + 5 = \frac{6 \times 2}{2} = 2$ and $f(8) = 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 = \frac{8 \times 4}{2} = 16$.

Now, I didn't figure this out on my own. The answer comes from here: [Sloane's OEIS A023896](http://oeis.org/A023896).

As for why I like the Kronecker delta function, that's because I'm a demon.

Answer (score 5):

Assume $n>2$. Then, if $n/2$ is an integer, then $n/2$ is certainly not a totative. Now it's easy to see that if $k$ is a totative, then $n-k$ is also a totative. So we can split $\phi(n)$ totatives into $\phi(n)/2$ pairs $\{k,n-k\}$, each containing two distinct elements (because $n/2$ isn't a totative) which sum to $n$. So sum of all totatives is $n\cdot\phi(n)/2=\frac{n\phi(n)}{2}$