# Arithmetic mean of the integers in set $S=\{k:k\in \mathbb{Z}, 1\leq k\leq n$ and $gcd(k,n)=1\}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Or stated simply, what is the arithmetic mean of the [totatives](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Totative.html) of $n$?

From this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1147897/what-is-sum-of-totatives-of-nnatural-numbers-lt-n-coprime-to-n) I can see that the sum of the totatives is given by the formula $\large\frac{n\times\phi (n)}{2}\large$. So the required answer would then be $\frac{n}{2}$. What is a simpler or an alternative argument to prove this?

Answer (score 1):

Easier way: If $k$ is relatively prime to $n$, so is $n-k$.  So the numbers in $S$ can be paired up so that the sum of each pair is $n$.

Comment: Except when n=1 or 2, (Fairly trivial special case,)